# sharepoint application deployment error

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

**Hi 
I created a simple blank sharepoint application page( through Visual Studio 2010)
After run that page, sharepoint 2010 prompt this error.**

Server Error in '/' Application.
Runtime Error
Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed.

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on the local server machine, please create a  tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This  tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "RemoteOnly". To enable the details to be viewable on remote machines, please set "mode" to "Off".

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's  configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

**after changing in web.config ( customerror="Off" and callstack="true")
I get this error**

> Server Error in '/' Application. Parser Error Description: An error
>   occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this
>   request. Please review the following specific parse error details and
>   modify your source file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: This page has encountered a critical error.
>   Contact your system administrator if this problem persists.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 1:  <%@ Page
>   Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.TemplateRedirectionPage,Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing,Version=14.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"
>   %> <%@ Reference VirtualPath="~TemplatePageUrl" %> <%@ Reference
>   VirtualPath="~masterurl/custom.master" %><%@ Register
>   Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls"
>   Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> Line 2:   Line 3:
>
> Source File: /Pages/UserDashboard.aspx    Line: 1
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5466;
>   ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5459

**Any Idea, how I can solve this issue?**

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have your application page inheriting the Publishing Redirection page?

How did you create the application page, through Visual Studio or some other way?

[This MSDN guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231581.aspx) is a great start for learning how to create and deploy application pages to Sharepoint

or this for getting some great examples of how your page directive should look like: http://nishantrana.wordpress.com/2009/02/26/create-a-simple-hello-world-custom-application-page-in-sharepoint/ . E.g:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/_layouts/application.master" Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.LayoutsPageBase" %>
<asp:Content ID="Main" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
  <asp:Label Text="Hello World" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
</asp:Content>
```